# What is the best practice on whether/when to open a link in a new window/tab?

Tags: html

Is there a best practice on whether or when to open a new link in a new window/tab (versus forwarding the current window/tab to the new link)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is good practice to open the link in a new window/tab if:

1. The target is on another website and the user is likely to continue browsing your site after following it
2. The primary purpose of the link is to print the content, so it contains no navigation
3. The link is a detour from a standard workflow (ie a help page in the middle of a mutli-step form

Answer (score 8):

A good guiding principle in web design is the back button. It's the one piece of UI that virtually all web users know how to use.

Thus the only appropriate place to use links that open new windows is in states which can't be easily reached by the back button.

A prime example of this is links in the midst of forms:
[image: Example]

If the users click on the form then the back button will not get them to the state they were at - with the form being partially filled.

This is not to say that `target="_blank` links are the only or even a particularly good solution to this problem, but they are the one place where users are expecting them and they can be actually beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

Internet users like me are used to "open page in new tab", so, just leave all your link as normal :) But of course not everybody do that, but please reduce to as little as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when the new link points to an external resource users might want to keep the original page open. Otherwise the convention is not to confuse users and keeps links behave link links and navigate to a new page. Advanced users could always hold the shift/ctrl key to open a new tab/window

Answer (score 1):

Between whether to open a page in a new window versus in a new tab:

If you *need* to open the link in a new window or tab, use `target="_blank"`. You can either use a transitional doctype with your pages or use JavaScript to inject that attribute. The browser will decide, based on user settings, whether to open it in a new window or tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking best practice, there are only 2 reasons for opening a link in a new window/tab:

1. The user is logged into a secure environment, and leaving that environment forces the user to log-in again when they come back.
2. The user is in a multi-step form, and when they leave the form all answered values will rest, forcing the user to restart at the beginning.
3. There is a case to be made for things like PDFs, but you can force download them without automatically opening them in the browser. That is preferable. The browser will allow the user to open the document when it is downloaded, where it will automatically open in a new window.

In all other situations, it isn't user-friendly to force-open the link in a new window. You are forcing this because **YOU** want the user to remain on your website when following the link.

When the user wants to open the link in a new window/tab, and remain on your website, they can simply choose to do so. But if you force it, the user cannot choose to do the opposite.

In other words: Don't force open links in new windows/tabs, unless it is inconvenient for **the user** if you don't.

This is not just my personal opinion. This is supported by research done by W3C on digital accessibility, and one of the things they recommend: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G200.html

Answer (score -1):

Non developers will prefer to see a new window as this is more clarity to what they are reading. Developers and non-developers are a little different technically.